# Print statements in Spark 2.4.3

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I recently moved to spark 2.4.3 from 2.3.1 and since then I am seeing some unwanted lines being printed out when I try to create a dataframe

This is all I am doing from the pyspark shell

```
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]])
```

which results in the following being displayed on the terminal

```
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'function'>
<class 'function'>
<class 'function'>
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'code'>
<class 'type'>
<class 'function'>
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'bytes'>
<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'NoneType'>
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'bytes'>
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'dict'>
<class 'dict'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'dict'>
<class 'function'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'NoneType'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'dict'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'function'>
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'code'>
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'bytes'>
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'NoneType'>
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'bytes'>
<class 'type'>
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'dict'>
<class 'dict'>
<class 'NoneType'>
<class 'dict'>
<class 'NoneType'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'NoneType'>
<class 'type'>
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'dict'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'type'>
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'dict'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'bool'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'type'>
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'dict'>
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'dict'>
<class 'bool'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'int'>
```

I tried searching the spark folder to see if there is a rogue `print(type(x))` kind of statement but couldn't find one.

All the types that are being printed are python primitives but I cant seem to figure where it is coming from. What is causing is and how do I turn it off?

EDIT:
I am using spark 2.4.3, pyspark 2.4.3, python 3.7 and java 8

Comment: Have you tried to put a semicolon at the end of the line ? Don't know for sure but may be the reason behind this print.

Comment: @Rafaël Why so ?

Comment: In python, putting a semicolon means 'please don't print' when you're not assigning. For example : `spark.createDataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]])` would print something if you don't put semicolon at the end. In your case, you're assigning it to a variable so it shouldn't be a problem, but just in case this is some spark behaviour, it may be interesting to try. Not sure though, it's just a wild guess.

Comment: @Rafaël I tried that a few seconds ago. Doesn't suppress the prints.

Comment: @Rafaël, I did not know that, thank you very much !

Comment: @BlueSheepToken no worries ! OP, sorry to hear that :/

Comment: @BlueSheepToken isn't that semi-colon trick only for IPy notebooks?

Comment: @ClockSlave You might be right, I checked on a local python console, does not work

Comment: @ClockSlave That's correct, should have edited my comment, missed the point here anyway :)